# Passing user information from login script

Tags: php, authentication, login-script

I am trying to pass user data from my login script so anywhere else on the site when using sessions I can present the users information from the users tables when needed. As it currently stand I can only show the username, I have other information such as an email address, first name, last name etc:

```
<?php

ob_start();

include('db_con.php'); 

$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password']; 

$sql="SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql);


$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if($stmt->num_rows()) {
    $stmt->bind_result($hashed_password);
    $stmt->fetch();

    if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("location:home.php");
    } else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
 } else {
     echo "User is not found!";
 }

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Here is how my session is set:

```
<?php
// Uer sessions
session_start();
?>
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true): ?>

    <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
    <?php echo $_SESSION['emailAddress']; ?>
    <br />
    <?php echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>"; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

I am struggling to see how i can pass though the other details to the session to output them?

Comment: save the user id, then fetch the user from DB when you need the user data.

Comment: Am I doing that in the log in script? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that those additional details (like first name, last name, email address) are contained in your users database table?

If so you could modify your SQL query to grab those values, and then set session variables to store them.

For example (I'm assuming your columns are named 'firstname', 'lastname', and 'email'):

```
$sql="SELECT password, firstname, lastname, email FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
...
$stmt->bind_result($hashed_password, $firstname, $lastname, $email);
...
```

Then, when you've confirmed a password match, set the session variables with the correct values:

```
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
```

And, finally, output those values where-ever you like, such as:

```
echo $_SESSION['email'];
```

Comment: I missed out one thing when trying this for myself `$stmt->bind_result($hashed_password, $firstname, $lastname, $email);` thank you ever so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Hope it helped. If so, would you mind upvoting this answer? Cheers!